# Problem with abstract class inheritance and constructor at C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, virtual, abstract

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(int a) : a_(a) {
        //do something
        someMethod();
        //do something else
    };
protected:
    int a_;
    virtual void someMethod() = 0 {};
};

class Derived : Base {
public:
    Derived() {
        Base::Base(42);
    }
protected:
    void someMethod() override {
        //realisation
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived *obj = new Derived();
    delete obj;
}
```

This code doesn't work by two mistakes: base class's default constructor is needed and base class's constructor with parameters can't be called because of using abstract methods

My problem is that `someMethod()` realised in `class Derived` is not called at all when I create object of `class Derived`. Also I don't want to use default constructor of `class Base`, but compiler is swearing.

How can I correct my code to see functionality that I want?

Comment: `someMethod();` should be a big flashing error from your compiler. If it isn't, file a bug report ASAP. Or are you calling it indirectly? Also `virtual void someMethod() = 0 {};` is plain ill-formed. The code you posted has a few unrelated issues. I suggest you address them to avoid answers here from being derailed.

Comment: Short "solution": Don't ever call virtual functions from a constructor.

Comment: You can't call a virtual function from the constructor. The derived object is not created yet.

Comment: @super You can call virtual function from the constructor. But it will be dispatched statically i.e. to the implementation in the class that is being constructed. But that's not allowed if the function is *pure* virtual.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I correct my code to see functionality that I want?

1. Remove the call to a pure virtual function in the constructor of `Base`.
2. Call `someMethod` in the constructor of the derived class that overrides it instead.
3. Provide an initialiser to the `Base` subobject in the member initiliser list. If you don't provide an initialiser to the base, it will be default initialised.

Answer (score 0):

### Why this cannot work ?

This design will not work because of the way obects are constructed.

When you construct a `Derived`,  the first thing happening is that a `Base` object is constructed with a `Base` constructor. There is no `Derived` object at this moment, so if you'd invoke the virtual function in the `Base` constructor, it would be the virtual that would be valid for the `Base` class until you leave the `Base` constructor's body.

This is allowed by the standard, but with restrictions:

> **[base.class.init]/16**: Member functions (**including virtual member functions**) can be called for an object under construction. (...) However,
>   if these operations are performed in a ctor-initializer (or in a
>   function called directly or indirectly from a ctor-initializer) before
>   all the mem-initializers for base classes have completed, the program
>   has undefined behavior.

These restriction do not apply to virtual functions that are called from the constructor body, since the body is executed after all initializers.

But in your case the virtual function is pure virtual for the `Base`.  So it's UB according to the following clause:

> **[class.abstract]/6**: Member functions can be called from a constructor (or destructor) of an abstract class; the effect of making
>   a virtual call to a pure virtual function directly or
>   indirectly for the object being created (or destroyed) from such a
>   constructor (or destructor) is **undefined**.

### What is the alternative

There is unfortunately no other real alternative than using a [two step initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3021572/3723423) in which you first construct the object and then call an initialization function before using the object.

The only issue with this approach is the risk of forgetting the call to the initialization function.  You can protect you against this:

- using a flag to indicate if the intialization has taken place and check this flag in all member functions (yes, it's a little overhead).
- if you have an abstract class, you may perhaps use a factory pattern (factory method or abstract factory). You could then let the factory do the call.
- you may use the builder pattern, and make sure that the constructor is only visible to the builder who won't forget the initialization either.

### Other problems with your code

You must be careful about how you "call" the base constructor from the derived constructor:

```
class Derived : Base {
public:
    Derived() : Base(42) // this is the correct place !
    {  
    //Base::Base(42);  //<====  OUCH !!! NO !! This creates a temporary base object !!
    }
    ...
};
```

You'd also need to be careful about the pure virtuals (I don't know if it's a typo or if your compiler could compile your code):

```
virtual void someMethod() = 0;  // if it's abstract, no pending {} !
```